# Logstash forwarder error

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

Logstash forwarder

While running logstash forwarder I'm seeing skipping old file error.

```
**/opt/lumberjack/bin/lumberjack -config /etc/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.conf -from-beginning=true**
2015/01/13 14:47:30 publisher init
2015/01/13 14:47:30 {
"network": {
"servers": [ "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6782" ],
"ssl ca": "/etc/logstash-forwarder/server.crt",
"ssl key": "/etc/logstash-forwarder/server.key",
"timeout": 15
},
"files": [
{
"paths": [
"/opt/test/*.log"
]
}
]
}
```

> **2015/01/13 14:47:30.399484 Skipping old file: /opt/test/mc.l28.log**
>
> 2015/01/13 14:47:30.399598 Setting trusted CA from file:
>   /etc/logstash-forwarder/server.crt
>
> 2015/01/13 14:47:30.399938 Connecting to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx.:6782
>
> 2015/01/13 14:47:30.962701 Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6782

Answer (score 1):

logstash-forwarder doesn't want to keep old files open, which would consume system resources for files that seem stale.  The default is 24 hours.

In the latest code, you can change this value with the 'dead time' parameter.

Comment: I included dead time parameter in logstash forwarder still i'm seeing the same error.Look at this                       /opt/lumberjack/bin/lumberjack -config /etc/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.conf
2015/01/14 07:41:27 publisher init
2015/01/14 07:41:27 {
"network": {
"servers": [ "xxx.xxx.xxx:6782" ],
"ssl ca": "/etc/logstash-forwarder/server.crt",
"ssl key": "/etc/logstash-forwarder/server.key",
"timeout": 15
},
"files": [
{
"paths": [
"/opt/test/*.log"
],
"dead time":
["10m"]
}
]
}

2015/01/14 07:41:27.392331 Skipping old file: /mc.L27_SysCtrl_08_10#3a08-10-2014.log

Comment: 'dead time' is a new config option.  Check that your version supports it.